# Boot Repair failing to respond by e-mail

Tags: boot, boot-repair

I have been having boot problems.  So I downloaded Boot Repair and ran it.  It went and looked at GRUB, didn't like what it saw, and told me to remove and then reinstall it, which I duly did.  There was what it flagged as a "minor error" during this process, and I was rather worried about that because this machine is crotchety at the best of times; so when it asked me if I wanted to copy the process to a pastebin, I said yes.  As instructed, I wrote down the resulting URL at paste.ubuntu.com.  It told me that if I had any further boot problems, I should send the URL to boot.repair@gmail.com.

So the following morning, of course, I had further boot problems.  Specifically it told me that normal.mod was missing, and in fact when I went and investigated, it turned out that the *entire directory* that should have contained normal.mod was empty.  Nothing there.  (The corresponding directory in the grub.bak folder contains quite a lot of files, but it won't let me copy and paste them.)  Amazingly it somehow managed to boot anyway, though it took a lot of time and did various things it doesn't normally do in the process.

I duly sent the URL off to the Boot Repair people, expecting help.  I didn't get an answer.  I waited for about a week and then tried again.  Still nothing.  I waited another three days (we're now on today) and tried yet again.  And now I've just been looking on their site, and discovered two things: 1) the contents of the pastebin expire after a few days, so whatever went wrong on my computer is now lost to the world, and 2) the person who created Boot Repair, yannubuntu, hasn't been active for a year.  I am now wondering if they're dead.

I'm now sleeping my computer at night rather than shutting it down, because I'm afraid it's not going to boot; but I can't do that for ever.  Every time I do an update it tells me it wants a restart, and I'm going "you're not getting one till I work out how to fix your boot".

So, two related questions, really: 1) does anyone know what's happened to the Boot Repair people, and 2) what should I do about the computer?  (Note: I am not quite a novice, but on the other hand I'm also really not an expert, so if the solution is complicated I'll need walking through it slowly.)

Thank you!